# C or C++ : for loop variable

Tags: c++, c, for-loop

My question is a very basic one. In C or C++:

Let's say the `for` loop is as follows,

```
for(int i=0; i<someArray[a+b]; i++) {
 ....
 do operations;
}
```

My question is whether the calculation `a+b`, is performed for each `for` loop or it is computed only once at the beginning of the loop?

For my requirements, the value `a+b` is constant. If `a+b` is computed and the value `someArray[a+b]`is accessed each time in the loop, I would use a temporary variable for `someArray[a+b]`to get better performance.

Comment: Without optimization this will be calculated each time. If you turn on the optimizer, this will be most certain be optimized out (if you don't modify a or b within the loop).

Comment: because... i don't think it's required to do it one way or the other... it's probably going to be compiler-dependent.

Comment: Addition: If a and be are declared const, this even with the optimizer turned off the calculation might be left out.

Comment: @urzeit If the compiler can prove that you don't modify a or b in the loop.  There are a lot of cases where you won't modify them, but the compiler is unable to determine this.

Comment: Most decent compilers have a *constant folding* optimisation, which will move the calculation outside the loop *if* it can prove that the value can't change during the loop. But the only way to be sure is to look at the generated code. (Personally, I'd probably move it out of the loop anyway, if that doesn't hurt readability, but that's just me.)

Comment: @James Kanze: Of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find out, when you look at the generated code

```
g++ -S file.cpp
```

and

```
g++ -O2 -S file.cpp
```

Look at the output `file.s` and compare the two versions. If `someArray[a+b]` can be reduced to a constant value for all loop cycles, the optimizer will usually do so and pull it out into a temporary variable or register.

Answer (score 5):

It will behave *as if* it was computed each time. If the compiler is optimising and is capable of proving that the result does not change, it is allowed to move the computation out of the loop. Otherwise, it will be recomputed each time.

If you're certain the result is constant, and speed is important, use a variable to cache it.

Answer (score 3):

> is performed for each for loop or it is computed only once at the beginning of the loop?

If the compiler is not optimizing this code then it will be computed each time. Safer is to use a temporary variable it should not cost too much.

Comment: Premature micro-optimization if the values don't change loop over loop.

Answer (score 3):

First, the C and C++ standards do not specify how an implementation must evaluate `i<someArray[a+b]`, just that the result must be as if it were performed each iteration (provided the program conforms to other language requirements).

Second, any C and C++ implementation of modest quality will have the goal of avoiding repeated evaluation of expressions whose value does not change, unless optimization is disabled.

Third, several things can interfere with that goal, including:

- If `a`, `b`, or `someArray` are declared with scope visible outside the function (e.g., are declared at file scope) and the code in the loop calls other functions, the C or C++ implementation may be unable to determine whether `a`, `b`, or `someArray` are altered during the loop.
- If the address of `a`, `b`, or `someArray` or its elements is taken, the C or C++ implementation may be unable to determine whether that address is used to alter those objects. This includes the possibility that `someArray` is an array passed into the function, so its address is known to other entities outside the function.
- If `a`, `b`, or the elements of `someArray` are `volatile`, the C or C++ implementation must assume they can be changed at any time.

Consider this code:

```
void foo(int *someArray, int *otherArray)
{
    int a = 3, b = 4;
    for(int i = 0; i < someArray[a+b]; i++)
    {
        … various operations …
        otherArray[i] = something;
    }
}
```

In this code, the C or C++ implementation generally cannot know whether `otherArray` points to the same array (or an overlapping part) as `someArray`. Therefore, it must assume that `otherArray[i] = something;` may change `someArray[a+b]`.

Note that I have answered regarding the larger expression `someArray[a+b]` rather than just the part you asked about, `a+b`. If you are only concerned about `a+b`, then only the factors that affect `a` and `b` are relevant, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

The calculation is performed each `for` loop. Although the optimizer can be smart and optimize it out, you would be better off with something like this:

```
// C++ lets you create a const reference; you cannot do it in C, though
const some_array_type &last(someArray[a+b]);
for(int i=0; i<last; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is an alternative spelling which avoids scoping problems: `for (int i=0, last=someArray[a+b]; i<last; ++i)`

Comment: @Angew This would work only if `someArray` is of type `int[]`.

Comment: @JohnDibling It conveys the fact that `a+b` is not going to change to the reader of your program. If the loop is long, readers may want to see what happens to `a` and `b` inside the loop; if you rewrite with an explicit stop, the readers would know that they don't need to look any further.

Comment: I see.  If `a` and `b` are locals, IMO it would be better to make them `const`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight re:`int[]` Yes indeed, but that's quite likely (epsecially since the question also concerns C).

Comment: In that case, how is it better than `const some_array_type last = someArray[a+b];`? Seems far more readable to be than using a reference. And it works in C too. Performance-wise, there shouldn't be much of a difference.

Comment: @Lundin That would be shorter, but it wouldn't be equivalent: only `a+b` is guaranteed to not change, but `someArray[a+b]` may change. Hence the reference is better.

Comment: In my opinion, it is unwise to write for loops where the variables inside the condition are dynamically changed during the execution of the loop body. I would probably have written a while loop instead for such a case, since the number of iterations wouldn't be known in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how good the compiler is, what optimization levels you use and how `a` and `b` are declared.

For example, if `a` and/or `b` has `volatile` qualifier then compiler has to read it/them everytime. In that case, compiler can't choose to optimize it with the value of `a+b`. Otherwise, look at the code generated  by the compiler to understand what your compiler does.

There's no standard behaviour on how this is calculated in neither C not C++.

Answer (score 1):

I will bet that if `a` and `b` do not change over the loop it is optimized. Moreover, if `someArray[a+b]` is not touched it is also optimized. This is actually more important since since *fetching* operations are quite expensive.

That is with any half-decent compiler with most basic optimizations. I will also go as far as saying that people who say it does always evaluate are plain wrong. It is not always for certain, and it is most probably optimized whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

It calculates every time. Use a variable :)

Comment: "Use a variable":  *Why?*

Comment: Explain why they should use a variable, answer without reasoning, proof, or justification is of little value.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile it and check the assembly code just to make sure.

But I think most compilers are clever enough to optimize this kind of stuff. (If you are using some optimization flag)

Answer (score 0):

It might be calculated every time or it might be optimised. It will depends on whether `a` and `b` exist in a scope that the compiler can guarantee that no external function can change their values. That is, if they are in a global context, the compiler cannot guarantee that a function you call in the loop will modify them (unless you don't call any functions). If they are only in local context, then the compiler can attempt to optimise that calculation away.

Generating both optimised and unoptimised assembly code is the easiest way to check. However, the best thing to do is not care because the cost of that sum is so incredibly cheap. Modern processors are very very fast and the thing that is slow is pulling in data from RAM to the cache. If you want to optimised your code, profile it; don't guess.

Comment: In real application problem would not be the summation, but fetching from the table. Still might be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation `a+b` would be carried out every iteration of the loop, and then the lookup into `someArray` is carried out every iteration of the loop, so you could probably save a lot of processor time by having a temporary variable set outside the loop, for example(if the array is an array of `ints` say):

```
int myLoopVar = someArray[a+b]
for(int i=0; i<myLoopVar; i++) 
{
 ....
 do operations;
}
```

**Very simplified explanation:**

If the value at array position `a+b` were a mere 5 for example, that would be 5 calculations and 5 lookups, so 10 operations, which would be replaced by 8 by using a variable outside the loop (5 accesses (1 per iteration of the loop), 1 calculation of `a+b`, 1 lookup and 1 assignment to the new variable) not so great a saving.  If however you are dealing with larger values, for example the value stored in the array at `a+b` id 100, you would potentially be doing 100 calculations and 100 lookups, versus 103 operations if you have a variable outside the loop (100 accesses(1 per iteration of the loop), 1 calculation of `a+b`, 1 lookup and 1 assignment to the new variable).

The majority of the above however is dependant on the compiler: depending upon which switches you utilise, what optimisations the compiler can apply automatically etc., the code may well be optimised without you having to do any changes to your code.  Best thing to do is weigh up the pros and cons of each approach specifically for your current implementation, as what may suit a large number of iterations may not be most efficient for a small number, or perhaps memory may be an issue which would dictate a differing style to your program . . . Well you get the idea :)

Let me know if you need any more info:)

Answer (score 0):

for the following code:

```
int a = 10, b = 10;
for(int i=0; i< (a+b); i++) {} // a and b do not change in the body of loop
```

you get the following assembly:

```
L3:
    addl    $1, 12(%esp)     ;increment i
L2:
    movl    4(%esp), %eax    ;move a to reg AX
    movl    8(%esp), %edx    ;move b to reg BX
    addl    %edx, %eax       ;AX = AX + BX, i.e. AX = a + b
    cmpl    12(%esp), %eax   ;compare AX with i
    jg  L3                   ;if AX > i, jump to L3 label
```

if you apply the compiler optimization, you get the following assembly:

```
    movl    $20, %eax   ;move 20 (a+b) to AX
L3:
    subl    $1, %eax    ;decrement AX
    jne L3              ;jump if condition met
    movl    $0, %eax    ;move 0 to AX
```

basically, in this case, with my compiler (MinGW 4.8.0), the loop will do "the calculation" regardless of whether you're changing the conditional variables within the loop or not (haven't posted assembly for this, but take my word for it, or even better, don't and disassemble the code yourself).

when you apply the optimization, the compiler will do some magic and churn out a set of instructions that are completely unrecognizable.

if you dont feel like optimizing your loop through a compiler action (-On), then declaring one variable and assigning it `a+b` will reduce your assembly by an instruction or two.

```
int a = 10, b = 10;
const int c = a + b;
for(int i=0; i< c; i++) {}
```

assembly:

```
L3:
    addl    $1, 12(%esp)
L2:
    movl    12(%esp), %eax
    cmpl    (%esp), %eax
    jl  L3
    movl    $0, %eax
```

*keep in mind, the assembly code i posted here is only the relevant snippet, there's a bit more, but it's not relevant as far as the question goes*